# crawler4j always returns fatal transport error

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

This is what I get for any seed I add to crawler4j.

```
ERROR [Crawler 1] Fatal transport error: Connection to http://example.com refused while fetching http://example.com/page.html (link found in doc #0)
```

This is really weird for me. I don't know what causes it.

Comment: What happens when you visit `http://example.com/page.html` in a browser from the same system?

Comment: It does not open the page! :D That was a network problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to increase the politeness setting of the crawler. It always happens to me when the server that I want to crawler is not good.

Comment: this is not an more a comment